# Modify class attributes javascript CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript, I tried to change the color of an element (circle) when clicking on a button but it doesn't work for me and i don't know what to do, here is the script:
I have 2 files(html and css):

**html file:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> <title> www.tothemoon.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="Mpage.css"/>
    
    </head>
    
    <body> 
     <button  id= "but" onclick="FM()"  style="font-size:50px; background-color:blue; border:none">try me </button>
     <div class="circle", style="color:#1c87c9"> text </div>
     <script>
     
     var cir=document.querySelector(".circle");
     function FM(){
         cir.style.backgroundColor ="yellow";  
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS file:**

```
.circle {
background-color: #ccb22e;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
```

}

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? I'm wondering if the comma in your div.circle could be causing any problems.

Comment: Also, it worked fine for me in JSFiddle.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have presented so could you check via your browser's devtools inspect facility that you haven't got any errors in the console? The only thing I can think of at the moment is that your CSS file isn't loading, but you would still see a change in color so I am stumped. Also, making your code into a snippet which we can run (and which you have tested to ensure it shows the problem) would be very helpful, otherwise I think your question needs to be closed as non-reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works great, it's exactly the code you attached

```css
.circle {
background-color: #ccb22e;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> <title> www.tothemoon.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="Mpage.css"/>
    
    </head>
    
    <body> 
     <button  id= "but" onclick="FM()"  style="font-size:50px; background-color:blue; border:none">try me </button>
     <div class="circle", style="color:#1c87c9"> text </div>
     <script>
     
     var cir=document.querySelector(".circle");
     function FM(){
        if(cir.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
            cir.style.backgroundColor  = "#ccb22e";
         else
            cir.style.backgroundColor ="yellow";  
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It works only on the first click but if i click a second time it doesn't work. we have to refresh the page if we want to repeat the operation.

Comment: @mulan I fixed the code to work all the time, if this is the answer you were looking for I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as the correct answer

Comment: Use script tag inside the head tag to load the js first then body of the page while making DOM tree.

Comment: @Rizwan it was working good but when i have moved the script tag inside the head as you proposed, it generates these errors: page3.html:                                                                        `9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at FM (page3.html:9:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (page3.html:107:104)`

Comment: @mulan It is impossible to transfer it to the head because you are searching the DOM for elements that have not yet been created because the body has not been written yet, the current position of the script is indicated.
If you want to do it better, export the script to an external JS file

Comment: then it mean there is a dependency,  Jquery can solve your problem in a very simple way. if you would use the Jquery, it will allow you to load your JS code when page is loaded properly, as like below
`$(function()
{
  // your code
});`
this only when you implemented jQuery.
OR

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});`